# UITableView lazy-loaded image does not load until finger is off

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, asynchronous, lazy-loading

I have an app where I load a lot of large images. When I lazy-load them, and even after the image has been loaded, the cell does not load them until I take my finger off the screen. I am calling my `downloadImageForVisiblePaths` function in the `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods `scrollViewDidEndDragging` and in `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` apart from this, I am also setting the image in the `UITableView`'s `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method like so:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

//     Code to load reusable custom cell

CustomObject *object = (CustomObject*) [self.tableArray objectAtIndex: indexPath];

if(!object.mainImage){

    [self downloadImageForIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.mainImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"];

}else{

    cell.mainImageView.image = object.mainImage;

}

    return cell;
}
```

Where the `downloadImageForIndexPath` looks like this:

```
-(void) downloadImageForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) indexPath{

    UIImage *loadedImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];

    // take url and download image with dispatch_async

    // Once the load is done, the following is done

    CustomCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.mainImageView.image = loadedImage;

    CustomObject *object = (CustomObject*) [self.tableArray objectAtIndex: indexPath];

    object.mainImage = loadedImage;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.tableVIew reloadData];
        });
}
```

I can't see where I am going wrong. I need the images to load even when the finger is on the screen. This behaviour is similar to how the images load on apps like Google+, Instagram or Facebook.

Any pointers will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell since you didn't include all the code for `downloadImageForIndexPath`, but it looks like you are assigning an image to a cell from a background thread (you shouldn't touch UI controls from background threads). Also, if you'r updating cell directly, you don't need to call `reloadData`.

I would also suggest using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) for displaying remote images in a tableview.

Comment: Well I am actually setting the image on the main thread and only getting the image in the background thread. I'm trying out SDWebImage now. Will let you know how it goes.

Comment: SDWebImage works perfectly. One question though. Wont apple give me warnings about using non-public selectors when I try to release the app?

Comment: Everything in SDWebImage is public and there are many apps in the app store using it.